# Rust CLI tool to synchronize files to S3

Tags: console, rust, amazon-web-services

Learning Rust, I've written a small CLI tool which will

1. Fetch the existing data in S3
2. Iterate through local folders
3. Upload the files which don't exist in S3

I'd be keen to hear anything I might have done that doesn't follow Rust best practices.

````rust
use async_recursion::async_recursion;
use aws_sdk_s3::error::ListObjectsV2Error;
use aws_sdk_s3::model::{ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass};
use aws_sdk_s3::output::{ListObjectsV2Output, PutObjectOutput};
use aws_sdk_s3::{error::PutObjectError, ByteStream, Client, Region, SdkError};
use log::{debug, error, info, warn};
use shellexpand;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::str::FromStr;
use structopt::StructOpt;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum BackupError {
    #[error("Could not parse path")]
    InvalidPath,

    #[error("Invalid storage class")]
    InvalidStorageClass,

    #[error("Invalid server side encryption")]
    InvalidServerSideEncryption,

    #[error("S3 upload failed")]
    UploadFailed(#[from] SdkError<PutObjectError>),

    #[error("Failed to retrieve data from server")]
    FileFetchFailed(#[from] SdkError<ListObjectsV2Error>),
}

pub type BackupResult<T> = Result<T, BackupError>;

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
struct Options {
    /// Directory to backup
    #[structopt(parse(from_os_str))]
    path: std::path::PathBuf,

    /// AWS region
    #[structopt(default_value = "eu-west-2", short, long)]
    region: String,

    /// Bucket to store data in
    #[structopt(short, long)]
    bucket: String,

    /// The storage class for the individual files
    /// Accepted values:
    /// ```
    ///  DEEP_ARCHIVE
    ///  GLACIER
    ///  GLACIER_IR
    ///  INTELLIGENT_TIERING
    ///  ONEZONE_IA
    ///  OUTPOSTS
    ///  REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
    ///  STANDARD
    ///  STANDARD_IA
    /// ```
    #[structopt(default_value = "DEEP_ARCHIVE", short, long)]
    storage_class: String,

    /// The encryption used by the individual files
    /// Accepted values:
    /// ```
    ///  AES256
    ///  aws:kms
    /// ```
    #[structopt(default_value = "AES256", short, long)]
    encryption: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::init_from_env(
        env_logger::Env::default().filter_or(env_logger::DEFAULT_FILTER_ENV, "info"),
    );

    let args = Options::from_args();
    let client = match S3Client::new(
        &args.bucket,
        args.region,
        &args.storage_class,
        &args.encryption,
    )
    .await
    {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(err) => panic!("Unable to establish S3 client: {}", err),
    };

    let mut files_by_path = match fetch_existing_objects(&client).await {
        Ok(files) => files,
        Err(error) => panic!("Failed to fetch objects: {}", error),
    };

    info!("Found {} objects", files_by_path.len());

    let root = match expand_path(args.path) {
        Ok(p) => p,
        Err(error) => panic!("Failed to read root path: {}", error),
    };

    let second = root.clone();
    match traverse_directories(
        &root,
        &second,
        &mut files_by_path,
        &client,
        &client.bucket,
        &client.storage_class,
        &client.encryption,
    )
    .await
    {
        Ok(()) => info!("All directories synced"),
        Err(err) => error!("Failed to sync directories: {}", err),
    }
}

async fn fetch_existing_objects(
    client: &S3Client,
) -> Result<HashSet<Vec<String>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut files_by_path = HashSet::<Vec<String>>::new();
    let mut next_token: Option<String> = None;

    loop {
        let response = client.fetch_existing_objects(next_token).await?;
        for object in response.contents().unwrap_or_default() {
            let filename = match object.key() {
                Some(name) => name.to_owned(),
                None => panic!("No filename found!"),
            };

            let filename_pieces = split_filename(&filename);
            files_by_path.insert(filename_pieces);
        }

        next_token = response.next_continuation_token().map(|t| t.to_string());
        if !response.is_truncated() {
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok(files_by_path)
}

fn expand_path(input: PathBuf) -> BackupResult<PathBuf> {
    let expanded_path: String = shellexpand::tilde::<String>(&parse_path(input)?).to_string();
    return Ok(Path::new(&expanded_path).to_owned());
}

fn split_filename(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    return filename
        .split(&['/', '\\'][..])
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .collect();
}

#[async_recursion]
async fn traverse_directories(
    path: &Path,
    root: &Path,
    existing_files: &mut HashSet<Vec<String>>,
    client: &S3Client,
    bucket: &str,
    storage_class: &StorageClass,
    sse: &ServerSideEncryption,
) -> BackupResult<()> {
    // We use metadata since path::is_file() coerces an error into false
    let metadata = match fs::metadata(path) {
        Ok(m) => m,
        Err(err) => {
            warn!("Unable to read the metadata for {:?}: {}", path, err);
            return Ok(());
        }
    };

    if metadata.is_file() {
        debug!("Processing {:?}", path.file_name());
        let stripped_path = match strip_path(path, &root) {
            Some(p) => p,
            None => return Ok(()),
        };
        let filename_segments = split_filename(&stripped_path);

        if existing_files.contains(&filename_segments) {
            info!("Skipping existing file: {}", stripped_path);
            return Ok(());
        }

        info!("Uploading new file: {}", stripped_path);
        existing_files.insert(filename_segments);

        let file_data = ByteStream::from_path(path).await;
        match file_data {
            Ok(data) => {
                client.upload_file(data, stripped_path.as_ref()).await?;
            }
            Err(err) => {
                error!("Failed to read file {:?}: {}", stripped_path, err);
            }
        }
        return Ok(());
    }

    debug!("Diving into new directory: {:?}", path);

    for entry in fs::read_dir(path).unwrap() {
        let directory = entry.unwrap();
        let directory_name = parse_path(directory.path())?;

        info!("Evaluating {}", directory_name);
        traverse_directories(
            &directory.path(),
            root,
            existing_files,
            &client,
            bucket,
            storage_class,
            sse,
        )
        .await
        .unwrap();
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn parse_path(path: PathBuf) -> BackupResult<String> {
    return match path.into_os_string().into_string() {
        Ok(parsed_path) => Ok(parsed_path),
        Err(err) => Err(BackupError::InvalidPath),
    };
}

fn strip_path(path: &Path, root: &Path) -> Option<String> {
    let path = match path.strip_prefix(root) {
        Ok(p) => match p.to_str() {
            Some(p) => p,
            None => {
                error!("Failed to parse path: {:?}", path);
                return None;
            }
        },
        Err(err) => {
            error!("Failed to parse path {:?}: {}", path, err);
            return None;
        }
    };

    return Some(path.to_owned());
}

pub struct S3Client {
    s3_client: Client,
    bucket: String,
    storage_class: StorageClass,
    encryption: ServerSideEncryption,
}

impl S3Client {
    pub async fn new(
        bucket: &str,
        region: String,
        storage_class: &str,
        sse: &str,
    ) -> BackupResult<S3Client> {
        let region = Region::new(region);
        let aws_config = aws_config::from_env().region(region).load().await;
        let client = Client::new(&aws_config);

        let storage_class = match StorageClass::from_str(storage_class) {
            Ok(class) => class,
            Err(err) => return Err(BackupError::InvalidStorageClass),
        };

        let sse = match ServerSideEncryption::from_str(sse) {
            Ok(enc) => enc,
            Err(err) => return Err(BackupError::InvalidStorageClass),
        };

        return Ok(S3Client {
            s3_client: client,
            bucket: bucket.to_owned(),
            storage_class,
            encryption: sse,
        });
    }

    pub async fn upload_file(&self, data: ByteStream, key: &str) -> BackupResult<PutObjectOutput> {
        let upload_response = self
            .s3_client
            .put_object()
            .bucket(&self.bucket)
            .key(key.replace("\\", "/"))
            .body(data)
            .set_storage_class(Some(self.storage_class.to_owned()))
            .server_side_encryption(self.encryption.to_owned())
            .send()
            .await;

        match upload_response {
            Ok(output) => Ok(output),
            Err(err) => Err(BackupError::UploadFailed(err)),
        }
    }

    pub async fn fetch_existing_objects(
        &self,
        continuation_token: Option<String>,
    ) -> BackupResult<ListObjectsV2Output> {
        let response = self
            .s3_client
            .list_objects_v2()
            .bucket(&self.bucket)
            .set_continuation_token(continuation_token.or(None))
            .send()
            .await;

        match response {
            Ok(output) => Ok(output),
            Err(err) => Err(BackupError::FileFetchFailed(err)),
        }
    }
}
````

If it is easier, you can also read the code on Github: https://github.com/Vannevelj/backup-rs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks good! You've used `thiserror` and `clap` (through `structopt`) which is nice.
I would also recommend using [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) to catch some of the most common mistakes and to suggest idiomatic improvements.

**Here are my suggestions:**

Remove `use shellexpand;` as it is not used.

---

All the cases where you match on a result and panic in the error arm can be replaced with `unwrap_or_else`.

**Example**

Before:

```rust
let mut files_by_path = match fetch_existing_objects(&client).await {
    Ok(files) => files,
    Err(error) => panic!("Failed to fetch objects: {}", error),
};
```

After:

```rust
let mut files_by_path = fetch_existing_objects(&client)
    .await
    .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Failed to fetch objects: {}", err));
```

---

No need to use the return keyword when returning the last expression in a function.

**Example**

Before:

```rust
fn split_filename(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    return filename
        .split(&['/', '\\'][..])
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .collect();
}
```

After:

```rust
fn split_filename(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    filename
        .split(&['/', '\\'][..])
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .collect()
}
```

---

Avoid specifying types where they can be inferred.

**Example**

Before:

```rust
let expanded_path: String = shellexpand::tilde::<String>(&parse_path(input)?).to_string();
```

After:

```rust
let expanded_path = shellexpand::tilde(&parse_path(input)?).to_string();
```

---

Replace `from_str` with `from` where `from_str` has `Infallible` error type.

**Example**

Before:

```rust
let storage_class = match StorageClass::from_str(storage_class) {
        Ok(class) => class,
        Err(err) => return Err(BackupError::InvalidStorageClass),
};

let sse = match ServerSideEncryption::from_str(sse) {
        Ok(enc) => enc,
        Err(err) => return Err(BackupError::InvalidStorageClass),
};
```

After:

```rust
let storage_class = StorageClass::from(storage_class);
let sse = ServerSideEncryption::from(sse);
```

---

Dynamic dispatch can be avoided here:

```rust
async fn fetch_existing_objects(
    client: &S3Client,
) -> Result<HashSet<Vec<String>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
```

because the function only returns one error type.

```rust
async fn fetch_existing_objects(client: &S3Client) -> BackupResult<HashSet<Vec<String>>>
```

---

Use `map_err` instead of matching if you want to transform errors.

**Example**

Before:

```rust
let response = self
    .s3_client
    .list_objects_v2()
    .bucket(&self.bucket)
    .set_continuation_token(continuation_token.or(None))
    .send()
    .await;

match response {
    Ok(output) => Ok(output),
    Err(err) => Err(BackupError::FileFetchFailed(err)),
}
```

After:

```rust
self.s3_client
    .list_objects_v2()
    .bucket(&self.bucket)
    .set_continuation_token(continuation_token)
    .send()
    .await
    .map_err(BackupError::FileFetchFailed)
```

---

The `bucket` parameter in the `new` method of the `S3Client` can also be of type `String` like the `region` parameter.

---

Use `expect` instead of `match` when you want to panic with a custom message if a result is error.

Before:

```rust
let filename = match object.key() {
    Some(name) => name.to_owned(),
    None => panic!("No filename found!"),
};

let filename_pieces = split_filename(&filename);
```

After:

```rust
let filename = object.key().expect("No filename found!");
let filename_pieces = split_filename(filename);
```

Also, there is no need to convert `filename` to `String`.

---

You can directly return from the loop inside the `fetch_existing_objects(..)` method instead of breaking.

Before:

```rust
if !response.is_truncated() {
    break;
}
```

After:

```rust
if !response.is_truncated() {
    return Ok(files_by_path);
}
```

---

Avoid `unwrap`s, they should either `panic` with a meaningful message or return an error.

---

I would personally redesign the recursive asynchronous function to avoid the tail recursion.

Also `bucket`, `storage_class` and `sse` parameters in the `traverse_directories()` method are never used.

---

**Final Code (Not tested):**

````rust
use aws_sdk_s3::error::ListObjectsV2Error;
use aws_sdk_s3::model::{ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass};
use aws_sdk_s3::output::{ListObjectsV2Output, PutObjectOutput};
use aws_sdk_s3::{error::PutObjectError, ByteStream, Client, Region, SdkError};
use log::{debug, error, info, warn};
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use structopt::StructOpt;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum BackupError {
    #[error("Could not parse path")]
    InvalidPath,

    #[error("Invalid storage class")]
    InvalidStorageClass,

    #[error("Invalid server side encryption")]
    InvalidServerSideEncryption,

    #[error("S3 upload failed")]
    UploadFailed(#[from] SdkError<PutObjectError>),

    #[error("Failed to retrieve data from server")]
    FileFetchFailed(#[from] SdkError<ListObjectsV2Error>),
}

pub type BackupResult<T> = Result<T, BackupError>;

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
struct Options {
    /// Directory to backup
    #[structopt(parse(from_os_str))]
    path: std::path::PathBuf,

    /// AWS region
    #[structopt(default_value = "eu-west-2", short, long)]
    region: String,

    /// Bucket to store data in
    #[structopt(short, long)]
    bucket: String,

    /// The storage class for the individual files
    /// Accepted values:
    /// ```
    ///  DEEP_ARCHIVE
    ///  GLACIER
    ///  GLACIER_IR
    ///  INTELLIGENT_TIERING
    ///  ONEZONE_IA
    ///  OUTPOSTS
    ///  REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
    ///  STANDARD
    ///  STANDARD_IA
    /// ```
    #[structopt(default_value = "DEEP_ARCHIVE", short, long)]
    storage_class: String,

    /// The encryption used by the individual files
    /// Accepted values:
    /// ```
    ///  AES256
    ///  aws:kms
    /// ```
    #[structopt(default_value = "AES256", short, long)]
    encryption: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::init_from_env(
        env_logger::Env::default().filter_or(env_logger::DEFAULT_FILTER_ENV, "info"),
    );

    let args = Options::from_args();
    let client = S3Client::new(
        args.bucket,
        args.region,
        &args.storage_class,
        &args.encryption,
    )
    .await
    .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Unable to establish S3 client: {}", err));

    let mut files_by_path = fetch_existing_objects(&client)
        .await
        .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Failed to fetch objects: {}", err));

    info!("Found {} objects", files_by_path.len());

    let root =
        expand_path(args.path).unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Failed to read root path: {}", err));

    match traverse_directories(&root, &mut files_by_path, &client).await {
        Ok(()) => info!("All directories synced"),
        Err(err) => error!("Failed to sync directories: {}", err),
    }
}

async fn fetch_existing_objects(client: &S3Client) -> BackupResult<HashSet<Vec<String>>> {
    let mut files_by_path = HashSet::new();
    let mut next_token: Option<String> = None;

    loop {
        let response = client.fetch_existing_objects(next_token).await?;
        for object in response.contents().unwrap_or_default() {
            let filename = object.key().expect("No filename found!");
            let filename_pieces = split_filename(filename);
            files_by_path.insert(filename_pieces);
        }

        next_token = response.next_continuation_token().map(|t| t.to_string());
        if !response.is_truncated() {
            return Ok(files_by_path);
        }
    }
}

fn expand_path(input: PathBuf) -> BackupResult<PathBuf> {
    let expanded_path = shellexpand::tilde(&parse_path(input)?).to_string();
    Ok(Path::new(&expanded_path).to_owned())
}

fn split_filename(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    filename
        .split(&['/', '\\'][..])
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .collect()
}

async fn traverse_directories(
    root: &Path,
    existing_files: &mut HashSet<Vec<String>>,
    client: &S3Client,
) -> BackupResult<()> {
    let mut paths = vec![root.to_owned()];

    while !paths.is_empty() {
        let path = paths.remove(0);
        debug!("Diving into directory: {:?}", path);

        // We use metadata since path::is_file() coerces an error into false
        let metadata = match fs::metadata(&path) {
            Ok(m) => m,
            Err(err) => {
                warn!("Unable to read the metadata for {:?}: {}", &path, err);
                continue;
            }
        };

        if metadata.is_file() {
            debug!("Processing {:?}", path.file_name());
            let stripped_path = match strip_path(&path, root) {
                Some(p) => p,
                None => continue,
            };
            let filename_segments = split_filename(&stripped_path);

            if existing_files.contains(&filename_segments) {
                info!("Skipping existing file: {}", stripped_path);
                continue;
            }

            info!("Uploading new file: {}", stripped_path);
            existing_files.insert(filename_segments);

            match ByteStream::from_path(path).await {
                Ok(data) => {
                    client.upload_file(data, stripped_path.as_ref()).await?;
                }
                Err(err) => {
                    error!("Failed to read file {:?}: {}", stripped_path, err);
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        for entry in fs::read_dir(path).unwrap() {
            let directory = entry.unwrap();
            paths.push(directory.path())
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn parse_path(path: PathBuf) -> BackupResult<String> {
    path.into_os_string()
        .into_string()
        .map_err(|_| BackupError::InvalidPath)
}

fn strip_path(path: &Path, root: &Path) -> Option<String> {
    let path = match path.strip_prefix(root) {
        Ok(p) => match p.to_str() {
            Some(p) => p,
            None => {
                error!("Failed to parse path: {:?}", path);
                return None;
            }
        },
        Err(err) => {
            error!("Failed to parse path {:?}: {}", path, err);
            return None;
        }
    };

    Some(path.to_owned())
}

pub struct S3Client {
    s3_client: Client,
    bucket: String,
    storage_class: StorageClass,
    encryption: ServerSideEncryption,
}

impl S3Client {
    pub async fn new(
        bucket: String,
        region: String,
        storage_class: &str,
        sse: &str,
    ) -> BackupResult<S3Client> {
        let region = Region::new(region);
        let aws_config = aws_config::from_env().region(region).load().await;
        let client = Client::new(&aws_config);

        let storage_class = StorageClass::from(storage_class);
        let sse = ServerSideEncryption::from(sse);

        Ok(S3Client {
            s3_client: client,
            bucket,
            storage_class,
            encryption: sse,
        })
    }

    pub async fn upload_file(&self, data: ByteStream, key: &str) -> BackupResult<PutObjectOutput> {
        let upload_response = self
            .s3_client
            .put_object()
            .bucket(&self.bucket)
            .key(key.replace("\\", "/"))
            .body(data)
            .set_storage_class(Some(self.storage_class.to_owned()))
            .server_side_encryption(self.encryption.to_owned())
            .send()
            .await;

        match upload_response {
            Ok(output) => Ok(output),
            Err(err) => Err(BackupError::UploadFailed(err)),
        }
    }

    pub async fn fetch_existing_objects(
        &self,
        continuation_token: Option<String>,
    ) -> BackupResult<ListObjectsV2Output> {
        self.s3_client
            .list_objects_v2()
            .bucket(&self.bucket)
            .set_continuation_token(continuation_token)
            .send()
            .await
            .map_err(BackupError::FileFetchFailed)
    }
}
````

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'll take some time tonight to properly go through your notes but this looks very interesting.